# Access denied for 'sec_user'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql, apache

for the life of me I cannot get this thing to work.
I am running an apache server, but my local sites are stored in **/www/Matthew/wwwroot/** and I access them in browser using http://Matthew.dev.

MySQL is running on a server called 'Matthew.dev', with a user called 'sec_user' with a host of 'Matthew.dev'.

Though, when I am trying to connect to my database using these credentials my error suggests that localhost is coming into play from somewhere, and I don't have a clue as to why.

Here is my psl-config.php:

```
<?php

define("HOST", "Matthew.dev");
define("USER", "sec_user");
define("PASSWORD", "vmWmtRhaYbGAw6US");
define("DATABASE", "lets_make_pi");

define("CAN_REGESTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

define("SECURE", FALSE);

?>
```

And here is my db_connect.php:

```
<?php

include_once 'psl-config.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}   
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

?>
```

The error:

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'sec_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /www/sites/Matthew/wwwroot/LetsMakePi/includes/db_connect.php on line 4
Failed to connect to MySQL: (1045) Access denied for user 'sec_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Warning: main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /www/sites/Matthew/wwwroot/LetsMakePi/includes/db_connect.php on line 9

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to connect to localhost.

(EDIT: More to the point, perhaps, it's trying to connect *from* localhost.)

What does the domain name Matthew.dev resolve to on that host?  (I've seen plenty of /etc/hosts where the local machine's fqdn is associated with 127.0.0.1 (aka localhost).)

For that matter, why not use localhost?  It's the same machine, no?  Just assign the same privileges to `sec_user@localhost` as for `sec_user@Matthew.dev`.

Comment: How do I stop it from connecting to localhost?

Comment: Make sure Matthew.dev does not resolve to localhost, I guess.  But why bother?  Why not let it access through localhost?

Comment: Hang on, Matthew.dev exists globally, resolving to 127.0.53.53?  Yeah, that's localhost all right.  So, as I was closing my answer:  Just assign the same privileges to `sec_user@localhost` as for `sec_user@Matthew.dev`.

Comment: I don't even have a sec_user@localhost user.  Or is that my problem?

I followed a guide (https://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/) and to be honest, I'm not quite sure what is going on anymore.

Comment: @MatthewAdair When you're trying to connect as that user, not having it is a problem, yes. :) See, you're trying to connect to 127.0.53.53 (the server) from 127.0.0.1 (localhost).  So the user trying to get access (to the server) is `sec_user@localhost`.

Comment: As it turns out, you are correct.
Thank you kid sir.